# How to prevent an activity from being initialized multiple times

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Android app, when a user taps a button multiple times quickly, same activity is initialized multiple times.

To prevent this, I added `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in Manifest file. But now, when an activity calls itself, it doesn't work.

I also tried

```
Intent myintent = getIntent();
myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

But this didn't work either.

How can I prevent having multiple activities when user clicks a button multiple times quickly, and how can I have same activity call itself correctly. Thanks.

Comment: try launchMode="singleTop". Edit: What do you mean by "and how can I have same activity call itself correctly" ? Do you want that activity to get recreated if it is called from itself?

Comment: @Wukash It didn't work, still an activity can't call itself.

Comment: @Wukash When I'm on an activity, and press a button and call the same Activity, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Wukash yes, I want that activity to get created with different values.

Comment: Well then you'll have to call `finish();startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this,  Activity.class));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this happens if you are "trigger happy". You can also in many situations use multi-touch to activate a bunch of options at the same time. If you really need to solve this, you can look at disabling elements like J Whitfield suggested (`element.setEnabled(false)` or `element.setClickable(false)`) or intercepting `onTouch`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try disabling the button after the first click has been detected.

```
Button button = theView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.isEnabled()){
                    v.setEnabled(false);
                }
                //Call your new activity here
                ...activity stuff...
            }
        });
```

Comment: I've updated my question to show how this can be implemented

Comment: With this configuration, when user goes back to previous activity, he can't use that button...

Comment: then just re-enable the button in the activities onstart()